# How to reload fragments in ViewPager Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I've huge data at database side and I'm retrieving data using a service in batch of 50 rows and putting that data in ViewPager fragments. It's working fine, but I need to re-call service once user reached at page 50 and need to update fragments with new data. Currently, I'm calling service in override newInstance(string message) method of Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.

Is there any way to update fragments with new data dynamically in Xamarin Anadroid?

Comment: `public static MyFragment NewInstance(int playId)` here is same function in the xamarin android fragment.

Comment: Mike, you are right. I used this method to initiate new fragment. But I'm looking for solution, if I already have fragments in view pager, How to recall it with different param when user reaches 50th fragment.

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.Replace(Android.Resource.Id.Content, details);` call replace and commit function in fragment transaction with same resource id. it will reload the fragment.

Comment: Yes, but how to detect that user is on 50th page of view pager and he is trying to slide for new page. If I will be able to detect this then I call any method to replace current fragments.

Comment: `viewPager.SetOnPageChangeListener` you can detect which page you selected. Update it in the adapter.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I was using this method. but my problem was different. Now I'm able to detect and re-call services if user reaches at 50th page and trying to slide left. I used gesture with view pager and detecting swipe if user sliding left after reaching 50. Then I'm replacing fragments in ViewPager.

Comment: Oh I see, Did you want to update 50th page when the user at 49 page and try to swipe to 50th page?

Comment: Yes Mike , once user reaches 49, I need to request another 50 rows using service and need to recreate activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the specific viewpager fragment. I think you do not need to recreate the activity or recreate the fragment.

Try to use the `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()` to update the fragment.

follow the setps to update the sepcific viewpager fragment：

**1. Create a handler**

```
    class MyHandler : Handler
        {
            public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                if (msg.What == 1)
                {
                    mainAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

**2. send message when you reach the 50th fragment**

```
    class PageChangeListen : Java.Lang.Object, IOnPageChangeListener
        {
            public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
            {

            }

            public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
            {

            }

            public void OnPageSelected(int position)
            {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.What = 1;
                    new MyHandler().SendMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        }
```

**3. in the main thread you will received the message and call `NotifyDataSetChanged`**

**4. add the update interface for the fragment**

```
    public interface Updateable
    {
         void update();
    }


    public class MyFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, Updateable
    {

        TextView questionBox;
        public MyFragment() { }

        public static MyFragment NewInstance(String question)
        {
            MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
            return fragment;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragmentLayout, container, false);
            questionBox = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
            return view;
        }

        public void update()
        {
            questionBox.Text = "Mike Update";
        }
  }
```

**5. fragment will update the UI by call `GetItemPosition`.**

```
     public override int GetItemPosition(Object @object)
            {
                MyFragment f = (MyFragment)@object;
                System.Console.WriteLine(f.Id + "" + f.Resources + "" + f.Tag);
                if (f != null)
                {
                    f.update();
                }
                return base.GetItemPosition(@object);
            }
```

In my example I have update the second page with the text "Mike Update". You can change the update condition and content.

Screen shot:

[image]

The [git source code is here](https://github.com/mikexxma/ViewPager_Fragment_Update)

Comment: Thank you Mike, I was looking for this. It's very helpful.

Comment: Hi Mike, It's working and I'm able to load new data from service. But fragments are not getting refreshed. Could you please help me.

Comment: Use the handler. Sending a new message when you update the fragment

Comment: MIke, I am using the same approach as you suggested and it's working in simple solution. But it's not working in my case. I have one drawer layout with content frame and I am loading fragments in this frame on selecting drawer item. Every drawer item has multiple fragments.

Comment: So when you click the drawer item, you can not update the fragment?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem. I solved this as i changed the FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Only show at first time

```
class ViewPagerPageAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Also show when you reload the Fragment

```
class ViewPagerStatePagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```